# What do we call a person who is creating layouts for webpages?

Tags: css, layout, web, html

For a few days now i am looking for a `webdesigners` who can make my page look nice. All i can find is people that are making .psd files of websites so i can cut out elements and put them on my page. I don't need that. I want someone, who will visit my page, look through my .css file, remake it, and maybe add few graphic elements on site - like logo and/or some icons.

I would do it by myself, but i am very bad at selecting/coupling colors, so i need someone to do it for me.

So, reasuming: how do i search through google to actually find people that can make my page look good by remaking my .css files?

Answer (score 2):

People still go by the umbrella term Web Designers : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HireAndPayADesignerAndBeHappy.aspx

I generally search css web designers to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

Altho this area may seem gray there are a few professionals involved on different aspects of what you want.

The reason behind the confusion is that the same professional might occupy more than one role.

A Web Designer should be be able to do that. And it is required of one the basic knowledge of CSS/HTML alongside with your description.

A Web Ui Engenier is the specialist on CSS/HTML/JavaScript he wont design the interface per say He is the guy who implements it.

And a Web UX Designer is the person who will design the user interface and experience. How it should behave and the UI engenier will implement it.